# How to remove X characters after a certain word throughout a file

Tags: bash

How would I remove the 18 characters that follows every occurrence of the word "GMOD" within a file, in bash?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(GMOD\).\{18\}/\1/g' input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

AWk alternative:

```
awk -v RS="(GMOD)" '{ $0=substr($0,18);ORS="GMOD";print }' file
```

Set the record separator to GMOD and then strip the first 18 characters of the record with substr.